# How to get Azure Speech Synthesis SDK / API to work in a Python container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I am trying to get Azure Speech Synthesis SDK / API to work in a Python container.

Just trying the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=linux%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-python) in a Python container CLI will get the error message:

```
Speech synthesis canceled: CancellationReason.Error
Error details: USP error: timeout waiting for the first audio chunk
Did you set the speech resource key and region values?
```

Yes, the resource key and region values are correct. If I run the quickstart in the localhost CLI, it works. But if I run the quickstart in the container CLI, I get the above error message.

I know there is an OpenSSL limitation so I tried with both Ubuntu 22 (and installed OpenSSL 1.1.1.1) and Ubuntu 20, but both have the same problem. Both works in localhost CLI but not in container CLI.

Is it a container port problem or the Azure SDK / API problem?

I am running on Ubuntu 20 virtualbox client and containers using docker compose. I have included the compose, dockerfile, requirements.txt below:

Docker Compose:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  # Define our indimyual services
  myapp:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    environment:
       - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
       - PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
    expose:
      - 8888
    networks:
      - my-network

  myserver:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: myserver
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use the Python3.10 container image
FROM python:3.8.10

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .


ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off


RUN apt update && apt install -y build-essential gcc ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 wget nano unzip gdebi -y \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt 
    
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# Create a uwsgi log directory and files
RUN mkdir /var/log/uwsgi
RUN touch /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi_access.log
RUN touch /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi_error.log


# run the command to start uWSGI
CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```

Requirements.txt

```
-i https://pypi.python.org/simple
uwsgi==2.0.22
werkzeug==2.3.6; python_version >= '3.8'
azure-ai-textanalytics==5.2.0
azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.31.0
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.28.0; python_version >= '3.7'
flask==2.3.2
jinja2==3.1.2; python_version >= '3.7'
requests==2.31.0; python_version >= '3.7'
uwsgi==2.0.22
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443; 
    server_name  localhost;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: curl --location --request GET 'https://YOUR_RESOURCE_REGION.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list' \
--header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_RESOURCE_KEY' gives something or error from container ?

Comment: inside container:
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to eastasia.tts.speech.microsoft.com:443. 

I received the correct response when using the desktop terminal.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a log from Speech SDK?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-use-logging

Comment: ...I think I am going to just switch to Google or others instead...

Comment: For others, please see docker documentation for speech here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/ai-services/speech-service/speech-container-overview

Comment: yes, I saw this before...but the hardware requirement to run the text-to-speech container is 6-core, 12GB memory!! I just want to run the SDK/API, not the whole speech models.